# Mostrar SELECT dependiendo del nombre?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp

Estoy haciendo varios hyperlinks que vayan a distinta URL. Esa URL se guarda en la base de datos y debe ir a la direccion que corresponda según la sección en la que esté. Seria pasar el parametro que corresponda mediante una variable? Yo tengo lo siguiente.

```
    string cadConexion = 
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["gestionTienda"].ConnectionString;
    MySqlConnection conexion = new MySqlConnection(cadConexion);
    MySqlCommand operacion = new MySqlCommand("select destino_enlace from tutoriales where nombre_pantalla='Cabecera'", conexion);

    conexion.Open();

    string url = Convert.ToString(operacion.ExecuteScalar());
```

Y por ejemplo tengo 2 hyperlinks que en realidad son más:

```
    HyperLink cabecera = new HyperLink();
    cabecera.ImageUrl = "~/Administracion/imagenes/icon_tutorial.png";
    // enlace_vista.ID = EquiposAyuda.ToString();
    cabecera.NavigateUrl = url;
    cabecera.Target = "_blank";
    cabecera.CssClass = "ImagenTutoriales";
    CabeceraAyuda.Controls.Add(cabecera);

    HyperLink inicio = new HyperLink();
    inicio.ImageUrl = "~/Administracion/imagenes/icon_tutorial.png";
    // inicio.ID = EquiposAyuda.ToString();
    inicio.NavigateUrl = url;
    inicio.Target = "_blank";
    inicio.CssClass = "ImagenTutoriales";
    InicioAyuda.Controls.Add(inicio);
```

Nombre_pantalla dependiendo de la sección es un nombre u otro. Como podria hacer para pasar los distintos nombres?

Un saludo y muchas gracias de antemano!!

Comment: Post editado para poner lo que tengo hecho. La idea es no hacer la misma consulta tantas veces como hyperlinks tengo creados.